# CKEDITOR : Attache "keydown" event after SetData?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I'm trying to do something in CKEditor.I made some Plugin's which has `event listener`

options.Ok, It's Working fine when I'm Starting the Editor.

But In my situation, I open some other Files in the mean time.So whenever user click the file i get the data and set Content to CKEditor using below code.

```
editor.setData('MY HTML FILE CONTENT');
```

It's working fine.But after I try to trigger the 'event listener' then it fails.

What Should I do now ?

Comment: Can you provide more details how you embed the editor and attach those listeners?
First thought is that you remove the dom element with listeners, that's why those stop working.

Answer (score 1):

Provided that you are doing this inside `init` method, please add the listener to the editor and not to the document. That way it will not get removed when document is removed:

```
editor.on( 'instanceReady', function( e ) {
    editor.on( 'key', function( e ) { 
        console.log('test');
    });
});
```

Please see: https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_editor.html#event-key

NOTE: the `instanceReady` event is not mandatory, you can use `pluginsLoaded` or just the `key` event. It depends which works the best for your use case.